# Identityserver4/OpenId Connect, Hybrid mode, Token Refresh Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have as ASP.net Core MVC site, that uses OpenId connect to authenticate with another ASP.net Core site, that uses IdentityServer4, that uses another IdentityServer4 site as identity provider.

On the client, there is a very few pages, that in theory could be used for a long time with only AJAX-calls. I wan't the site to refresh the access token, so that the user won't be forced to log in, let's say the next day.

I've set up a timer, that calls a WebAPI method on the MVC-site, that refreshes the token.

It works with the two first refreshes, but always fails on the third.

The method returns a JWT to be used on external API-calls. I can see this updates on the fist call as expected, and that it gets a new expiration timestamp.

In the third call, the tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync fails, because the refreshToken is null.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken()
    {
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(_authenticationOptions.Value.Authority);

        if (disco.IsError)
            return BadRequest(disco.Error);

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, _authenticationOptions.Value.ClientId, _authenticationOptions.Value.ClientSecret);
        var refreshToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);
        var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);

        if (tokenResult.IsError)
            return BadRequest(disco.Error);

        var old_id_token = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);
        var new_access_token = tokenResult.AccessToken;
        var new_refresh_token = tokenResult.RefreshToken;

        var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = old_id_token });
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = new_access_token });
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = new_refresh_token });

        var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "expires_at", Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });

        var info = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Cookies");
        info.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", info.Principal, info.Properties);

        return Ok(HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result);
    }
```

I can see, that Chrome is notifying in the console, that a set-cookie header is ignored, because it exceeds 4kb.

Any tips?

Comment: 4KB is a limit for cookies in **most** browsers: http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/  If you can make the payload smaller, or split it into more than one cookie, they could be saved then.

Comment: According to the spec there are _recommendations_, but the link I provided earlier is a more practical limit: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt see section 5.3 on limits.

Comment: My guess is that because there is no `try` / `catch` or any `null` checking, what you are seeing is the stack trace page in HTML in response to this action.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: I do not think that I have the power over those cookies. They are all set by the OpenId/IdentityServer middleware.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch : I don't get a stacktrace. tokenResult.IsError is true, so I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request as I should.
It just shouldn't be true ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The clients IdentityToken expired, and since that api method wasn't protected by [Authorize] attribute, it didn't renew + changed the script to use an iframe instead of AJAX-calls!

Case closed.